# in asp.net mvc im trying to create a view for the list of the users that are signing in

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view

im using the folders that are supplied with the asp.net web application .net framework , and I'm trying to create a view fo the users that are signing in but it doesn't work even that I did manage to create a view for the roles, I did the same thing with the users but here it just doesn't work

here is the controller code

```
public ActionResult Index( )    
{
    var Users = context.Users.ToList();
    return View(Users);
}
```

here is the view

```
@model List<A11_RBS.Models.ApplicationDbContext>
....
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(DbModel => Model)</th>            
    </tr>
    @if (Model.Count() == 0)
    {
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7">No records match search criteria</td>
        </tr>
    }
    else
    {
         foreach (var item in Model)
         {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(DbModel =>item.Users)</td>
            </tr>
         }
     }
</table>
```

the error is :

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[A11_RBS.Models.ApplicationUser]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[A11_RBS.Models.ApplicationDbContext]'. 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

My guess is the problem in the model but I don't know what to do about it

Comment: The erroe is self explanatory. Change the view to `@model List<A11_RBS.Models.ApplicationUser>`

Comment: I did it , and after changing some more other stuff, it worked,thx !!

Answer (score 0):

change `ApplicationDbContext` to `ApplicationUser` as suggested by the exception
you are sending an applicationUser model to the view but you are trying to use it as an ApplicationDbContext.

```
 var Users = context.Users.ToList();
    return View(Users);
```